# Conversion of Metadata Plist string Failed

Tags: core-data

In xCode, I'm building an iPhone app with Core Data, and with Objective C Exceptions checked for the Build, I'm receiving the following error in the Console:

**Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 259.)" UserInfo=0x611c2c0 {NSUnderlyingException=An error occurred converting the metadata plist: Conversion of string failed. The string is empty.}, {
    NSUnderlyingException = "An error occurred converting the metadata plist: Conversion of string failed. The string is empty.";
}**

This occurs when I try to run the app on the Simulator, and the app dies. When I try to run the app on my device (iPhone 3g), the program runs with the expected DB with full functionality, but when I close the app, the app will not reload on the device.

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm thinking that my Core Data definition isn't communicating with the underlying DB, "mySites.sqlite" ? Perhaps, I should delete the xcdatamodel and redefine it?

Comment: Was able to solve the underlying issue with the error. The underlying issue(s) was related to a flawed - pre-populated SQLite DB. Without realizing it, the column definitions were wiped out when I imported data from a CSV file. I've read many solutions as to what steps one should take to pre-populate the DB, and I'd be happy to share the steps, if anyone has the same issue. Thanks

Comment: I clean the projects, reset Simulator and it works again. Don't know why